# Javascript Countdown Timer Counting Down Not Updating Seconds/Minutes Properly

Tags: javascript, countdowntimer

I have created a countdown timer. However, it does not count down properly. Instead of counting down per second or minutes, it counts down by hundreths and does not update properly. I created another counting up timer using the same code but it works properly counting up per increment - it counts up minutes everytime 60 seconds have passed. I'm wondering how I can make this timer count down properly.

JSBin:
http://jsbin.com/funiveremi/6/edit

Updated* Adding in the 60 Seconds Counter:
http://jsbin.com/hohusuvube/2/edit

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>User Input Timer</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="part2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1><div id="time">00:00:00</div></h1>
<div id="result"></div>
<button id="start" onclick ="startClock();" >Start</button>
<button id="stop" onclick="stopTimer();">Stop</button>
<button id="clear" onclick="resetTimer();">Reset</button>

</body>
</html>
```

JAVASCIPT

```
hundreths = 10;
seconds = 15;
minutes = 20; 


document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + hundreths;


var currentTime = document.getElementById('time');

var t;

function startClock() {
function add() {

    hundreths--;
    if (hundreths < 0) {
        hundreths = 0;
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            seconds = 0;
            minutes--;
        }
        if(minutes < 0) {
            seconds= 0;
            minutes= 0;
            stopTimer();

        }
    }



if (hundreths > 9 && seconds < 9) {
currentTime.innerHTML = "0" + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds + ":" + hundreths;
  }
else if ((seconds > 9 ) && (hundreths < 9)) {
currentTime.innerHTML = "0" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + "0" + hundreths;
}
else if((seconds > 9) && (hundreths > 9)) {
currentTime.innerHTML = "0" + minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + hundreths;
}
else if ((minutes > 9) && (seconds < 9) && (hundreths < 9)) {
currentTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds + ":" + "0" + hundreths;
}

else if ((minutes > 9) && (seconds > 9) && (hundreths < 9)) {
currentTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + "0" + hundreths;
}

else if ((minutes > 9) && (seconds > 9) && (hundreths < 9)) {
currentTime.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds + ":" + hundreths;
}

else {
currentTime.innerHTML = "0" + minutes + ":" + "0" + seconds + ":" + "0" + hundreths;
}

   timer();
} // end function add();


function timer() {
    t = setTimeout(add, 100);
}
timer();
} // end function startClock();

function stopTimer() {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "<p>" + ("Your time is: " + minutes + " minutes, " + seconds + " seconds, " + "and " + hundreths + " hundreths") + "</p>";
    clearTimeout(t);
} // end function stopTimer();


function resetTimer() {
clearTimeout(t);

  currentTime.innerHTML = "00:00:00";
} // end function resetTimer();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Jquery Countdown plugin.

http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/

The implementation will be easier. something like this.

```
<div id="getting-started"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#getting-started").countdown("2016/01/01", function(event) {
    $(this).text(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work, you had the logic about when to set seconds incorrect so it was constantly resetting itself. One of the best things to do in these kinds of cases if you're stuck is to simply try changing the if statements, remove some of them and play with different values. It can help teach you what's really happening in a system, and give you a clue as to what is wrong. Another tip is just to read the code aloud to yourself in normal English. As you read it aloud you will often realize you're mistakes by hearing yourself say the logic.

```
    hundreths--;
    if (hundreths < 0) {
        hundreths = 10;
        seconds--;
        if (seconds < 0) {
            seconds = 59;
            minutes--;
        }
        if(minutes < 0) {
            seconds= 0;
            minutes= 0;
            stopTimer();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! Those are all very useful tips